# How to loop through row values to only return specific value?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I currently have this code to import values from a csv file:

```
def parse_csv_dns(self, csv_file):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file.split('\n'), delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        if len(row) > 1:
            if len(row) >= 10:
                event = {
                    'Timestamp': self.format_date(row[0], self.input_date_format, self.output_date_format),
                    'Policy Identity': row[1],
                    'Identities': row[2].split(','),
                    'InternalIp': row[3],
                    'ExternalIp': row[4],
                    'Action': row[5],
                    'QueryType': row[6],
                    'ResponseCode': row[7],
                    'Domain': row[8],
                    'Categories': row[9].split(',')
                }
                try:
                    event['Policy Identity Type'] = row[10]
                except IndexError:
                    pass
                try:
                    event['Identity Types'] = row[11].split(',')
                except IndexError:
                    pass
                try:
                    event['Blocked Categories'] = row[12].split(',')
                except IndexError:
                    pass
            else:
                event = {"message": convert_list_to_csv_line(row)}
            event = self.convert_empty_string_to_null_values(event)
            event['EventType'] = 'dnslogs'
            yield event
```

In the "action" row on row 5, there can be "allowed" or "blocked". How would I be able to retrieve only rows that have the value of "blocked"? I was thinking of looping through another if statement though I am not an expert in python scripting.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, why don't you just use pandas?

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure what that is, though this snippet comes from a script from Azure themselves which I try to tweak a little to fit our needs. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, you can do something like if event["Action"] == "blocked": continue. Continue keyword goes to next iteration in enclosing for loop. It won't go to your yield statement

Comment: @hasdrubal so I just put that line under the "for row in csv_reader:" line?

Comment: I'd put it within the  if len(row) >= 10:  block so that you know the row has the Action column. And withing a nice try / except block such as shown for other columns such as Identity Types.

Comment: @hasdrubal okay so right now I have

 if len(row) >= 10:
                    if event["Action"] == "Blocked": continue
                    event = { ... }
try:
                event['Action'] = row[5]
                    except IndexError:
                        pass

Sorry I'm not that experienced in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarize from the comments, you just need to add a `if` in your code to implement the requirement. But the code you provided in comments seems not correct. As hasdrubal mentioned, `continue` means exist current loop and go to next iteration, so you code should be like:

```
if len(row) >= 10: 
    if row[5] == "allowed": 
        continue       //exist current loop when row[5] equals "allowed" and go to next iteration
    event = { ... }
```

Or you can also not use `continue`, just with a "if" to judge the value of `row[5]`. The code should be like:

```
if len(row) >= 10: 
    if row[5] == "blocked": 
        event = { ... }
```